# binary search from txt excercise

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary

Write a program the reads whole numbers from a text file and then sorts the numbers. Then using the binary search algorithm from your notes (week6) Ask the user to enter a number and display what position the number is or not found if the number is not in the list.

my code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class myBinarySearch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        int target, found;
        int[] numArray = {36, 27, 29, 15, 16, 39, 11, 31};

        Arrays.sort(numArray);
        for(i=0; i <numArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print(numArray[i] + " ");

        System.out.print("\nEnter the number you are searching for: ");
        target = ReadKb.getInt();
        found = theBinarySearch(numArray, target);
        if(found == -1)
        System.out.println("Number not found");
        else
        System.out.println("Number: " +target +" found at position: " +found);
    }

    //Method searching using binary search algorithm
    private static int theBinarySearch(int []numArray, int target)
    {
        int mid,bottom,top;
        mid=0;
        bottom=0;
        top=numArray.length-1;
        while (top>= bottom)
        {
            mid=(top +bottom)/2;
            if(target==numArray[mid])
                break;
            else
                if(target<numArray[mid])
                    top=mid-1;
                else
                    bottom=mid+1;
        }

        if(target==numArray[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            return -1;
    }

}
```

and the txt document:

numbers.txt
 55
 12 
88
 33 
25 
5
 3
 23 
64
 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done code for `binarySerach` the only thing that is missing is to read it from file.

> How to read numbers from a file?

Try this one

```
    ....
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("resources/abc.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    Integer[] numArray = list.toArray(new Integer[] {});

    Arrays.sort(numArray);
    ....
```

---

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myBinarySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i;
        int target, found;
        // int[] numArray = { 36, 27, 29, 15, 16, 39, 11, 31 };

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("resources/abc.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        Integer[] numArray = list.toArray(new Integer[] {});

        Arrays.sort(numArray);
        for (i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++)
            System.out.print(numArray[i] + " ");

        System.out.print("\nEnter the number you are searching for: ");
        target = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        found = theBinarySearch(numArray, target);
        if (found == -1)
            System.out.println("Number not found");
        else
            System.out.println("Number: " + target + " found at position: " + found);
    }

    // Method searching using binary search algorithm
    private static int theBinarySearch(Integer[] numArray, int target) {
        int mid, bottom, top;
        mid = 0;
        bottom = 0;
        top = numArray.length - 1;
        while (top >= bottom) {
            mid = (top + bottom) / 2;
            if (target == numArray[mid])
                break;
            else if (target < numArray[mid])
                top = mid - 1;
            else
                bottom = mid + 1;
        }

        if (target == numArray[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Once again you have clearly helped me out BIGTIME! Braj you are top keep up the good work, thank you for helping me. It is strange cert 4 last year was Visual Basics now this year advanced diploma straight into Java thank you for all your help kindness much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined ReadKB. on my system it shows:

```
mohit@mohit:~/somewhere$ javac myBinarySearch.java 
myBinarySearch.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        target = ReadKb.getInt();
                 ^
  symbol:   variable ReadKb
  location: class myBinarySearch
```

choose something as

```
Scanner in = new Scanner();
and target = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: OP wants to do it in this way `new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()`. Read input from user.